# Is there a name in English for this kind of compact set?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, terminology, compactness

In French, they call “compact à bord régulier” a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $K=cl(int(K))$ and $\partial K$ is a finite union of piecewise $C^2$, disjoint and orientable (relatively to $K$) arcs. Is there a name for this in English? I haven’t been able to find it.

**Edit:** I think the boundary of such a set might be called a [staircase countour](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Staircase_Contour), but I’m not sure. Anyone can confirm?

Comment: How is an arc by itself, without an explicit parametrisation, differentiable?

Comment: Apple translate translates it to “ Compact with regular edge”. So maybe it’s a compact regular polygon?

Comment: I doubt you'll find an existing terminology that is widely recognized. If you wanted a less terse terminology that would be widely understood, perhaps you could call it something like a *compact subsurface of $\mathbb C$ with piecewise $C^2$ boundary.* Orientation is not necessary to specify; all such subsurfaces naturally inherit an orientation from $\mathbb C$ and then there is a naturally induced orientation on the boundary.

Comment: On second thought, though, your subset might not be a subsurface, so I'm not so sure my suggestion is quite in alignment with what you want.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think the boundary might be called a “staircase contour” according to [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Staircase_Contour), if by “smooth” we mean $C^2$ I guess…

Comment: If you read a little closer, you''ll see that the "staircase contour" is piecewise linear, whereas you are only requiring the boundary pieces to be $C^2$, not line segments. One issue with the definition is that a set being the closure of its interior is not a topological property: it depends on the larger topological space in which the set sits. For example, a closed interval has the property in $\Bbb R$, but embed that into $\Bbb R^2$, and its interior is empty, so there it does not have the property. This is a problem, because it is mostly topological properties that get named.

Comment: Lee Mosher's description of the boundary condition is perfect in my opinion. It is the description of the set as a whole that is problematic. There is no confusion about "compact", of course. It is only "is the closure of its interior" that is difficult to find an appropriate short description for. I thought of "perfect", but that is more broadly defined.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see... wouldn’t the larger topological space in this context be assumed to be $\mathbb{C}$, though?

Comment: Yes, but that misses my point, which was only that properties in topology with widely known names tend to depend only on the topology of the set itself, not on its inclusion in larger spaces. That your case has a specific larger space doesn't change this. However, I was thinking mostly of the topological condition, and this is clearly an analytic property. I vaguely recall this sometimes being called a "domain" or "regular domain" - but I have been unable to find a text mentioning it, so my memory is probably wrong.