# Is every simple closed contour in $\mathbb{C}$ the boundary of a compact set with the following property? (Two versions of Cauchy’s integral theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I’m reading some lecture notes in French where they give the following form of [Cauchy’s integral theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem):

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an open set $U \subset
> \mathbb{C}$. Then, for every oriented path $\Gamma$ such that
> $\Gamma=\partial K$ where $K\subset U$ is a compact set such that
> $K=cl(int(K))$ and $\partial K$ is a finite union of piecewise $C^2$,
> disjoint and orientable arcs. Then we have
>
> $$\int_{\Gamma} f(z)dz=0.$$

(There’s actually [a name](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665516/is-there-a-name-in-english-for-this-kind-of-compact-set?noredirect=1#comment9860157_4665516) in French for this kind of compact set, which I don’t know how to translate to English.)

I was trying to understand how this translates to the usual version of Cauchy’s integral theorem I already know, that is:

> If $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected open set $Ω$, then for any
> simply closed contour $C$ in $Ω$, the contour integral is zero:
>
> $$\int _{C}f(z)dz=0$$

…as the version on my lecture notes seems overly complicated to me.

In particular, I was wondering if any simple closed contour would satisfy or not the property of being the boundary of such a compact set. If not, what would a non-example look like?

Comment: Possibly the boundary of a fractal shape could be impossible to represent as a finite union of $C^2$ arcs? I'm not sure of any example, though.

Comment: A path is just a continuous map from a closed interval to $\mathbb C$? If so, writing $\Gamma = \partial K$ has to be read as "the image of $\Gamma$ is the set $\partial K$."

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I think so, but I don’t see right now what are the consequences of that…

Comment: @dahemar Then $\Gamma$ is nothing else than a piecewise $C^2$ simple closed curve. I don't see any reasonable use of $K$. Perhaps it is somewhere used in the proof in your notes, but that is pure speculation.

Comment: We have problems if the curve is not rectifiable.

Comment: @MathWonk Contours are usually defined as piecewise differentiable curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is every simple closed contour in $\mathbb C$ the boundary of a compact set with the following property?

Yes. A simple closed contour is a *Jordan curve*. The well-known Jordan curve theorem says that every simple closed curve in the plane separates the plane into a   bounded *interior* region and an unbounded *exterior* region. But more is true: The [Jordan-Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem) tells us that if $C \subset \mathbb C$ is a simple closed curve, then there is a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $h(C)$ is the unit circle $S^1$ in the plane. It is the boundary of the unit disk $D^2$ in the plane, thus $K = h^{-1}(D^2)$ is the desired compact subset having $C$ as its boundary.